# ANTLR4 no error messages while converting my grammar

Tags: powershell, antlr4, error-logging

the last few days/weeks I wrote ANTLR4 grammar and used it in my Javascript-React project.
While using the javascript runtime ( [see here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md) ), my console (powershell) always gave me an error message when my grammar was false or something was missing.

Now I'm out of town for a few weeks and had to install ANTLR4 + runtime on my laptop ( [scroll down to WINDOWS for the tutorial I used](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) ). This CLASSPATH stuff didn't worked for me, so I ignored it and .bat script didn't  worked for me either, like when I installed it for the first time.

My file structure looks like this:

[image]

When I go into my powershell and switch to the right folder and hit

```
.\antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=JavaScript .\FunktionLexer.g4
```

everything works fine and I have my token for the parser. This is probably exact the same installation I had before going out of town.

But when I use wrong grammar and hit the command just nothing happens. Like nothing, no output on my command line what could be wrong. I tryed to add parameter like -Xlog, which gives me a log until the grammar crashes, but it doesn't really tell me where it crashed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "use wrong grammar" mean? How can someone else reproduce this?

Comment: @BartKiers the easiest way is probably to use the command on a Parser without having tokens from the Lexer.  This should already create an error (of course not in my case). Can't share my Parser and Lexer with the public.

Comment: No lexer rules does not necessarily mean the grammar is incorrect. I don't ask you to post your entire grammar, just enough of a grammar so that others can (try to) reproduce the issue. As of  now, that is not possible.

Comment: And I also don't know what you mean by "the grammar crashes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the grammar (without lexer rules):

```
grammar FunktionLexer;

parse
 : .*? EOF
 ;
```

I can generate a lexer and parser just fine by running:

```
java -jar antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=JavaScript FunktionLexer.g4
```

You might want to edit your question and clearly indicate how someone can reproduce what you describe.

Comment: Note that my terminal won't let me execute jar files directly, but `java -jar antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar ...` is equivalent to what you do with `.\antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar ...`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem.  I don't know why "java -jar" and ".\" makes two different things, but after using "java -jar" I got error messages. Here is the screen: https://imgur.com/Zl6CKZW , as u can see I don't get any output with .\

Comment: @Ruffyg The recommended procedure is to use the Python-based ["antlr4 tool"](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-tools), i.e., `pip install antlr4-tools` then `antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript *.g4`, not `java -jar *.jar -Dlanguage=JavaScript *.g4` nor `.\*.jar -Dlanguage=JavaScript *.g4`. You may have a file association on Windows for a .jar different from your PATH variable. The antlr4 tool downloads a version of the Java runtime that is known to work with the .jar file, and tries to avoid the problems of setting up Java.